# Django FileField in model maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, django, django-models

My model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
        publish_date = models.DateField()
        file_1080p = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename_movie, validators=[validate_video])
        file_720p = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename_movie_720)
        file_480p = models.FileField(upload_to='temp/')
        subtitles = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename_subtitle_movie, validators=[validate_subtitles])
        already_converted = bool(False)
```

My save function:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.already_converted == False:
                    # todo convert files
                    self.already_converted = True
            if self.subtitles.path.endswith('.srt'): # srt subtitle should process
                    import re
                    m = re.sub(r'([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),([0-9]{3})', r'\1.\2', self.subtitles.read())
                    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
                    filenameToSave = generate_filename_subtitle_movie(0, self.subtitles.name)
                    self.subtitles.save(filenameToSave, ContentFile("WEBVTT\n\n" + m))
            super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error happens here: `self.subtitles.save(filenameToSave, ContentFile("WEBVTT\n\n" + m))`

Thanks.

Comment: And what is `self.subtitles` and `self.subtitles.save()`?

Comment: It is a `FileField`, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the `save` method on a `FileField` will trigger it's model's `save` method by default. You can bypass it by providing an additional third argument to the `FileField`'s `save` method.

```
self.subtitles.save(filenameToSave, ContentFile("WEBVTT\n\n" + m), False)
```

Have a look at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save